# Windows command prompt default directory randomly changing

Tags: windows, command-line, windows-10, environment-variables

What happens is when I'm on my windows and open a command prompt, I sometimes don't get the right default directory. Sometimes command prompt opens with "H:\", sometimes it's "c:\windows\System32" and sometimes "c:\Users\\Documents". The last one is the one that I want as default. For me it's not really a problem to change directories but when it's something different then the Documents option, git won't work because it can't find it's default directory. I think it has something to do with my environment variables but can't see what's wrong.

Currently my env vars are set as follows (only the ones I think are necessary):

User variables:

```
PATH = C:\Ruby22-x64\bin;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\;C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

System variables:

```
Path = %SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\wapt;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\CLI\wbin;C:\Program Files\Git\bin;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Windows Performance Toolkit;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin;C:\Ruby22-x64\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DTS\Binn\
```

I'm using Windows 10. If you need something else, please ask. Thanks!

Comment: How are you opening the `cmd` shell?

Comment: Windows key, type 'cmd', hit enter or choose Commandprompt in start menu

Comment: What directory is H:\ ? External/Internal drive, or a network drive?

Comment: H:\ is a network drive